# Firefox <select> dropdowns don't work in mobile

Tags: firefox

Firefox Quantum 60.0.1 Win7

When I go to the below linked site from PC, I can select the dropdowns from the select element.

If I hit F12 and and enable Responsive Design Mode select Google Nexus 6 (or any other), I can only hit the dropdown occasionally when I tap on it.

I've tried resetting (refreshing) Firefox, disabling all my addons, disabled javascript etc.

This bug is also reproducible on my boss's Samsung Galaxy and my BlackBerry KeyONE.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

Any ideas?